# ProcessOptions within AtBeginDocument does not work but ExecuteOptions does

Tags: class-options

When I have the following class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CustomClass}
\LoadClass[11pt]{article}

\DeclareOption{option1}{
    \texttt{Text 1}
    \clearpage
    \texttt{Text 2}
    \clearpage
}

\DeclareOption{option2}{
    \texttt{Text 3}
    \clearpage
    \texttt{Text 4}
    \clearpage
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \ProcessOptions
}

\endinput
```

And I use it in the following way:

```
\documentclass[option1]{CustomClass}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

No Pdf is generated. But when I use `ExecuteOptions{option1|option2}` is work but its static. So my option I specify when specifying the document class does not work.

Why is this happening?

Comment: put the `\AtBeginDocument` in both of the `\DeclareOption` not outside them, just have `\ProcessOptions` outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `\ProcessOptions` within the class or package file, so it knows which options to process.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CustomClass}
\LoadClass[11pt]{article}

\DeclareOption{option1}{
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \texttt{Text 1}%
    \clearpage
    \texttt{Text 2}%
    \clearpage
}%
}

\DeclareOption{option2}{
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \texttt{Text 3}%
    \clearpage
    \texttt{Text 4}%
    \clearpage
}%
}


 \ProcessOptions


\endinput
```